# LOAD DATA INFILE - Problem with optional quotes and commas

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, sql-insert, load-data-infile

I was using:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filePath'
     INTO TABLE demo
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

And I found out I had troubles when importing rows with cells containing JSON strings:

```
0, demo,"{""Name""=>""demo""}", 29, ...
```

Notice the `"{""Name""=>""demo""}"` part.

So I removed `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` and it fixed the problem.
However now I'm having troubles with a field with the value `"Korea, Republic of"`

```
13,"Korea, Republic of",demo,...
```

Is there any way I can manage these two cases at the same time?

Note: the input file is external to me, so I can't "re-structure" it.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you specify `"` as the escape character?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filePath'
     INTO TABLE demo
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Actually this seems to match one specific [documentation note](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html):

> To avoid ambiguity, occurrences of the `ENCLOSED BY` character within a field value can be doubled and are interpreted as a single instance of the character. For example, if `ENCLOSED BY '"'` is specified, quotation marks are handled as shown here:
>
> ```
> "The ""BIG"" boss"  -> The "BIG" boss`
> The "BIG" boss      -> The "BIG" boss
> The ""BIG"" boss    -> The ""BIG"" boss
> ```